# Нужно ли обособление?

Tags: сложности, пунктуация

Дано предложение:

"Директору филиала ОАО «ФСК ЕЭС» - МЭС Сибири".
Пояснение: МЭС Сибири является филиалом ФСК ЕЭС.
На мой взгляд, тире там не нужно, я бы просто написала "Директору филиала ОАО «ФСК ЕЭС» МЭС Сибири".

Я права? Или там все таки нужен какой-то знак препинания?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1. Директору филиала ОАО «ФСК ЕЭС» - МЭС Сибири. Запись неверна: здесь филиал ОАО «ФСК ЕЭС» - это приложение в препозиции, а МЭС Сибири  - определяемое слово. Поэтому нет обособления, тире не ставится.

Вариант 2. Директору филиала ОАО «ФСК ЕЭС» МЭС Сибири. Запись верная, но неясная, читается плохо.

Вариант 3. Директору  ОАО "МЭС Сибири" - филиала ОАО «ФСК ЕЭС. Можно предложить такой вариант. В этом случае приложение  после определяемого слова обособляется с помощью тире.

Answer (score 1):

И все же тире здесь уместно, так у данного ОАО есть, видимо, несколько филиалов, и тире заменяет слово "а именно". В целом это приложение, носящее пояснительный характер, а значит, оно выделяется тире, тем более что стоит в конце предложения